# PHP Warning demolishes JSON response

Tags: php, json

I'm implementing an ajax fileupload for my php application (using CodeIgniter).

I detect if the uploaded POST data is to large (>post_max_size) according to http://andrewcurioso.com/2010/06/detecting-file-size-overflow-in-php/ and try to send an appropriate JSON-encoded error response.

But the corresponding php warning included in the output completely destroys my JSON response !

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  POST Content-Length of 105906405 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
[{"error":"Posted data is too large. 105906405 bytes exceeds the maximum size of 8388608 bytes."}]
```

I don't want to parse and filter the warning out on client side, that seems ugly.
And disabling all php warnings globally seems inappropriate.

**Can I disable specific PHP warnings in the context of a php function? Or wrap it inside of a valid json response?**

Comment: You should have errors turned off in your production environment anyway...

Comment: @lonesomeday I agree, but the specified behaviour "give feedback to the user, if he tries to upload too large files" should be the same in production and development/testing environment. I'm not a fan of "Yea, but in production mode it works!" ;)

Comment: Typically errors on line 0 are startup errors, adding `php_flag display_startup_errors off` to your .htaccess should disable it... added that to my answer.

Answer (score 16):

*On production server:* Always disable php warnings.

*On development machine:*
Disable all warnings for that page for the purpose of testing and re-enable after testing is complete and functionality confirmed as working.

*Hint*: I prefer to have a variable globally set and depending on that enable or disable all php and database warning notifications. You could set that in `.htaccess` for example if you use apache.
I have this in `.htaccess`:

- production: `SetEnv DEVELOPMENT Off`
- development: `SetEnv DEVELOPMENT On`

And in the php code:

```
if( strtolower(getenv('DEVELOPMENT')) == "on" ) {
        ini_set("display_errors",2);
        ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL | E_STRICT);
}
```

To disable all errors from .htaccess use

```
php_flag display_startup_errors off
php_flag display_errors off
php_flag html_errors off
php_value docref_root 0
php_value docref_ext 0
```

If you want to get really tricky you could add a check like:

```
if(error_get_last() !== null)
```

and set a http header and check that from javascript both for json output and when loading your page and take a look at the error log or display the error on screen if you prefer that, still I strongly recommend that you disable the error showing code in the production environment.

For more in-depth talk about this take a look at [this article](http://perishablepress.com/advanced-php-error-handling-via-htaccess/).

Comment: I completely agree, but the code should eventually work fine with `display_errors` set to `on`. And in this specific case, that doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: @BartFriederichs Disable error reporting from php.ini or .htaccess. That has to work. Added code for that in my answer.

Comment: @BartFriederichs One of the 2 ways I suggested should work, check the last part of my answer for a way to both have some kind of error reporting and it not affecting your output directly!

Answer (score 3):

I have just had the same problem implementing an upload script which requires communication back to the calling script. Some php warnings were corrupting the output response.

I have resorted to the php output buffering functions. This is how I got rid of the warning output messages:

```
ob_start(); // start output buffering (we are at the beginning of the script)

[ ... ] // the script actual functionality is unchanged

ob_end_clean(); // this clears any potential unwanted output

exit($my_json_encoded_response); // and this just outputs my intended response
```

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a user-defined error handler: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

You can also use the output buffering functions to wrap it. `ob_start`, `ob_end_flush` and others.

However, it is always best to have PHP `error_reporting` set to `false` in production systems, then catch errors and wrap them in your JSON.

Comment: I'd like to use a custom event handler, but the documentation of your posted links says:
> If errors occur before the script is executed (e.g. on file uploads) the custom error handler cannot be called since it is not registered at that time.

Comment: Good one. Your specific problem seems to be more a server-centric problem than a script problem. The only quick thing I can think of now, is to disable warnings in the script.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just change the post max size on php.ini file:

```
post_max_size = 10M //change this line to whatever fits your needs
```

But depending on what the users should be uploading, you should also try checking the file size of the files that they're uploading.

Comment: But this doesn't prevent users to send files with a size of "post_max_size + 1"