# Work with php file outside public directory? I can access the file but receive error

Tags: javascript, php, directory-structure, fine-uploader

I'm starting to get frustrated and cannot work with a php file that is outside my public folder. I am using fineuploader and this php mini framework https://github.com/panique/mini.  I have the following file structure where “public” is my public directory.

```
application
--controller
----album.php
--libs
--model

public
--css
--img
--js
----application.js
```

I would like to use the php-file from a javascript in application.js. If I do like this and put s3demo in public/js folder everything works fine.

```
signature: {
        endpoint: url + "/js/application/s3demo.php"
    },
```

But I would like to have the s3demo.php in the application/libs folder instead of /js/application

I have using my controller with the following code

Javascript points to my controller instead of to the php-file

```
   signature: {
        endpoint: url + "/album/s3upload"
    },
```

And my controller looks like this

```
   public function s3upload() {
   require APP . '/libs/s3demo.php';
}
```

When I run the code I get the following error message in the browser NET tab -> Response

> Notice: Undefined index: _method in
>   /home/connecti/public_html/application/libs/s3demo.php on line 78
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/connecti/public_html/application/libs/s3demo.php:77) in
>   /home/connecti/public_html/application/libs/s3demo.php on line 103
>
> Notice: Undefined index: headers in
>   /home/connecti/public_html/application/libs/s3demo.php on line 109
>   {"invalid":true}

My controller can access my s3admin.php (I have a index named  “_method” in s3admin.php). But it feels like my php-file don’t know my javascript or something. What should I do to be able to runt s3demo.php from my libs folder? I don’t get any error if have have s3demo in the publicfolder and the fileupload works fine. If I have s3demo.php in my libs folder I get the error above and my file is not uploaded.

All javascript code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#fineuploader-s3').fineUploaderS3({
            request: {
                // REQUIRED: We are using a custom domain
                // for our S3 bucket, in this case.  You can
                // use any valid URL that points to your bucket.
                endpoint: "upload.fineuploader.com",

                // REQUIRED: The AWS public key for the client-side user
                // we provisioned.
                accessKey: "AKIAJB6BSMFWTAXC5M2Q"
            },

            template: "simple-previews-template",

            // REQUIRED: Path to our local server where requests
            // can be signed.
            signature: {
                endpoint: "/s3demo.php"
            },

            // OPTIONAL: An endopint for Fine Uploader to POST to
            // after the file has been successfully uploaded.
            // Server-side, we can declare this upload a failure
            // if something is wrong with the file.
            uploadSuccess: {
                endpoint: "/s3demo.php?success"
            },

            // USUALLY REQUIRED: Blank file on the same domain
            // as this page, for IE9 and older support.
            iframeSupport: {
                localBlankPagePath: "/server/success.html"
            },

            // optional feature
            chunking: {
                enabled: true
            },

            // optional feature
            resume: {
                enabled: true
            },

            // optional feature
            deleteFile: {
                enabled: true,
                method: "POST",
                endpoint: "/s3demo.php"
            },

            // optional feature
            validation: {
                itemLimit: 5,
                sizeLimit: 15000000
            },

            thumbnails: {
                placeholders: {
                    notAvailablePath: "assets/not_available-generic.png",
                    waitingPath: "assets/waiting-generic.png"
                }
            }
        })
            // Enable the "view" link in the UI that allows the file to be downloaded/viewed
            .on('complete', function(event, id, name, response) {
                var $fileEl = $(this).fineUploaderS3("getItemByFileId", id),
                    $viewBtn = $fileEl.find(".view-btn");

                if (response.success) {
                    $viewBtn.show();
                    $viewBtn.attr("href", response.tempLink);
                }
            });
    });
</script>
```

All php code in s3demo.php

```
<?php
/**
 * PHP Server-Side Example for Fine Uploader S3.
 * Maintained by Widen Enterprises.
 *
 *
 * This example:
 *  - handles non-CORS environment
 *  - handles size validation and no size validation
 *  - handles delete file requests for both DELETE and POST methods
 *  - Performs basic inspections on the policy documents and REST headers before signing them
 *  - Ensures again the file size does not exceed the max (after file is in S3)
 *  - signs policy documents (simple uploads) and REST requests
 *    (chunked/multipart uploads)
 *
 * Requirements:
 *  - PHP 5.3 or newer
 *  - Amazon PHP SDK (only if utilizing the AWS SDK for deleting files or otherwise examining them)
 *
 * If you need to install the AWS SDK, see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/guide/latest/installation.html.
 */

// You can remove these two lines if you are not using Fine Uploader's
// delete file feature
require 'aws/aws-autoloader.php';
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

// These assume you have the associated AWS keys stored in
// the associated system environment variables
$clientPrivateKey = $_SERVER['AWS_SECRET_KEY'];
// These two keys are only needed if the delete file feature is enabled
// or if you are, for example, confirming the file size in a successEndpoint
// handler via S3's SDK, as we are doing in this example.
$serverPublicKey = $_SERVER['PARAM1'];
$serverPrivateKey = $_SERVER['PARAM2'];

// The following variables are used when validating the policy document
// sent by the uploader. 
$expectedBucketName = "upload.fineuploader.com";
// $expectedMaxSize is the value you set the sizeLimit property of the 
// validation option. We assume it is `null` here. If you are performing
// validation, then change this to match the integer value you specified
// otherwise your policy document will be invalid.
// http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/develop/api/options.html#validation-option
$expectedMaxSize = null;

$method = getRequestMethod();

// This second conditional will only ever evaluate to true if
// the delete file feature is enabled
if ($method == "DELETE") {
    deleteObject();
}
// This is all you really need if not using the delete file feature
// and not working in a CORS environment
else if ($method == 'POST') {

    // Assumes the successEndpoint has a parameter of "success" associated with it,
    // to allow the server to differentiate between a successEndpoint request
    // and other POST requests (all requests are sent to the same endpoint in this example).
    // This condition is not needed if you don't require a callback on upload success.
    if (isset($_REQUEST["success"])) {
        verifyFileInS3();
    }
    else {
        signRequest();
    }
}

// This will retrieve the "intended" request method.  Normally, this is the
// actual method of the request.  Sometimes, though, the intended request method
// must be hidden in the parameters of the request.  For example, when attempting to
// send a DELETE request in a cross-origin environment in IE9 or older, it is not
// possible to send a DELETE request.  So, we send a POST with the intended method,
// DELETE, in a "_method" parameter.
function getRequestMethod() {

    if ($_POST['_method'] != null) {
        return $_POST['_method'];
    }

    return $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
}

function getS3Client() {
    global $serverPublicKey, $serverPrivateKey;

    return S3Client::factory(array(
        'key' => $serverPublicKey,
        'secret' => $serverPrivateKey
    ));
}

// Only needed if the delete file feature is enabled
function deleteObject() {
    getS3Client()->deleteObject(array(
        'Bucket' => $_POST['bucket'],
        'Key' => $_POST['key']
    ));
}

function signRequest() {
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $responseBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $contentAsObject = json_decode($responseBody, true);
    $jsonContent = json_encode($contentAsObject);

    $headersStr = $contentAsObject["headers"];
    if ($headersStr) {
        signRestRequest($headersStr);
    }
    else {
        signPolicy($jsonContent);
    }
}

function signRestRequest($headersStr) {
    if (isValidRestRequest($headersStr)) {
        $response = array('signature' => sign($headersStr));
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    else {
        echo json_encode(array("invalid" => true));
    }
}

function isValidRestRequest($headersStr) {
    global $expectedBucketName;

    $pattern = "/\/$expectedBucketName\/.+$/";
    preg_match($pattern, $headersStr, $matches);

    return count($matches) > 0;
}

function signPolicy($policyStr) {
    $policyObj = json_decode($policyStr, true);

    if (isPolicyValid($policyObj)) {
        $encodedPolicy = base64_encode($policyStr);
        $response = array('policy' => $encodedPolicy, 'signature' => sign($encodedPolicy));
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    else {
        echo json_encode(array("invalid" => true));
    }
}

function isPolicyValid($policy) {
    global $expectedMaxSize, $expectedBucketName;

    $conditions = $policy["conditions"];
    $bucket = null;
    $parsedMaxSize = null;

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($conditions); ++$i) {
        $condition = $conditions[$i];

        if (isset($condition["bucket"])) {
            $bucket = $condition["bucket"];
        }
        else if (isset($condition[0]) && $condition[0] == "content-length-range") {
            $parsedMaxSize = $condition[2];
        }
    }

    return $bucket == $expectedBucketName && $parsedMaxSize == (string)$expectedMaxSize;
}

function sign($stringToSign) {
    global $clientPrivateKey;

    return base64_encode(hash_hmac(
            'sha1',
            $stringToSign,
            $clientPrivateKey,
            true
        ));
}

// This is not needed if you don't require a callback on upload success.
function verifyFileInS3() {
    global $expectedMaxSize;

    $bucket = $_POST["bucket"];
    $key = $_POST["key"];

    // If utilizing CORS, we return a 200 response with the error message in the body
    // to ensure Fine Uploader can parse the error message in IE9 and IE8,
    // since XDomainRequest is used on those browsers for CORS requests.  XDomainRequest
    // does not allow access to the response body for non-success responses.
    if (getObjectSize($bucket, $key) > $expectedMaxSize) {
        // You can safely uncomment this next line if you are not depending on CORS
        header("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error");
        deleteObject();
        echo json_encode(array("error" => "File is too big!"));
    }
    else {
        echo json_encode(array("tempLink" => getTempLink($bucket, $key)));
    }
}

// Provide a time-bombed public link to the file.
function getTempLink($bucket, $key) {
    $client = getS3Client();
    $url = "{$bucket}/{$key}";
    $request = $client->get($url);

    return $client->createPresignedUrl($request, '+15 minutes');
}

function getObjectSize($bucket, $key) {
    $objInfo = getS3Client()->headObject(array(
            'Bucket' => $bucket,
            'Key' => $key
        ));
    return $objInfo['ContentLength'];
}
?>
```

Comment: *Undefined index*: Be sure you're initializing your variables before using them. I think [this question may be usefull to fix the "headers already sent"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Warning demolishes JSON response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12872515/php-warning-demolishes-json-response)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a notice message and then the headers cannot be sent. Disable the notice messages with error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE) at the beginning of your script;

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will test it. Can you explain why I get these error messages? For some reason it feels wrong to just disable them.

Comment: I think that the error is a notice that you are accessing to the $_POST['_method']. It would be better to use isset($_POST['_method']).